# sql join not taking all records from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have a query like this

```
WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT
        U.Name, U.Adluserid AS 'Empid', 
        MIN(CASE WHEN IOType = 0 THEN Edatetime END) AS 'IN',
        MAX(CASE WHEN IOType = 1 THEN Edatetime END) AS 'out',
        (CASE  
            WHEN MAX(E.Status) = 1 THEN 'AL' 
            WHEN MAX(E.Status) = 2 THEN 'SL' 
            ELSE 'L' 
         END) AS leave_status
    FROM
        Mx_ACSEventTrn
    RIGHT JOIN
        Mx_UserMst U ON Mx_ACSEventTrn.UsrRefcode = U.UserID
    LEFT JOIN
        Tbl_Zeo_Empstatus E ON Mx_ACSEventTrn.UsrRefcode = E.Emp_Id
    WHERE
        CAST(Edatetime AS DATE) BETWEEN '2019-11-03' AND '2019-11-03' 
    GROUP BY
        U.Name, U.Adluserid
)
SELECT 
    [Name], [Empid], [IN], [OUT],
    (CASE 
        WHEN CAST([IN] AS TIME) IS NULL THEN CAST(leave_status AS NVARCHAR(50))
        WHEN CAST([IN] AS TIME) < CAST('08:15' AS TIME) THEN 'P' 
        ELSE 'L' 
     END) AS status
FROM 
    CTE
```

In my employee master table `Mx_UserMst` I  have 67 employees. But here it is showing only a few employees those who are punched. I want to show all employees from employee master

Comment: No one but you knows your schema. Using an aggregate like MAX on a column named Status seems logically incorrect - but it is impossible to know. Casting Edatetime to date and then comparing it to the same date literal using between is overly complicated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the problem is his `WHERE` clause:

```
where cast(Edatetime as date) between '2019-11-03' and '2019-11-03'
```

Why not `cast(Edatetime as date) = '2019-11-03'`? 
I'm not sure in which table the column `Edatetime` belongs (you should qualify all the columns with the correct table name/alias).
You must move the condition to an ON clause:

```
WITH CTE AS 
(
  select U.Name,U.Adluserid as 'Empid', 
       min(case when IOType=0 then Edatetime end) as 'IN',
       max(case when IOType=1 then Edatetime end) as 'out',
       case max(E.Status) when 1 then 'AL' when 2 then 'SL' else 'L' end as leave_status
  from Mx_UserMst U
  left join Mx_ACSEventTrn on Mx_ACSEventTrn.UsrRefcode=U.UserID and (cast(Edatetime as date) between '2019-11-03' and '2019-11-03')
  left join Tbl_Zeo_Empstatus E on Mx_ACSEventTrn.UsrRefcode=E.Emp_Id 
  group by U.Name,U.Adluserid
)
SELECT [Name], [Empid],[IN],[OUT],
  case 
    when cast([IN] as time) is null then cast(leave_status as nvarchar(50))
    when cast([IN] as time) < cast('08:15' as time) then 'P' 
    else 'L' 
  end as status
FROM CTE
```

If `Edatetime` belongs to `Tbl_Zeo_Empstatus` move the condition to the next join's `ON` clause.
I also changed the `RIGHT` to a `LEFT` join so to make the statement more readable.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep everything in a particular table, then that should be the first table in the `FROM` clause.  Subsequent joins should be `LEFT JOIN`s and conditions on subsequent tables should be in the `ON` clause rather than the `WHERE` clause.

I would also advise you to use table aliases and to only use single quotes for string and date constants -- NOT column aliases.

The following assumes that `IOType` and `Edatetime` are in the table `Mx_ACSEventTrn`.  I should not have to guess.  You should qualify *all* column names in the query.

```
WITH CTE AS (
      SELECT U.Name, U.Adluserid AS Empid, 
             MIN(CASE WHEN AE.IOType = 0 THEN AE.Edatetime END) AS in_dt,
             MAX(CASE WHEN AE.IOType = 1 THEN AE.Edatetime END) AS out_dt,
             (CASE WHEN MAX(ES.Status) = 1 THEN 'AL' 
                   WHEN MAX(ES.Status) = 2 THEN 'SL' 
                   ELSE 'L' 
              END) AS leave_status
      FROM Mx_UserMst U LEFT JOIN
           Mx_ACSEventTrn AE
           ON AE.UsrRefcode = U.UserID AND
              CAST(AE.Edatetime AS DATE) BETWEEN '2019-11-03' AND '2019-11-03' LEFT JOIN
           Tbl_Zeo_Empstatus ES 
           ON AE.UsrRefcode = ES.Emp_Id AND               
      GROUP BY U.Name, U.Adluserid
     )
SELECT Name, Empid, IN_DT, OUT_DT,
       (CASE WHEN IN_DT IS NULL THEN leave_status
             WHEN CAST(IN_DT AS TIME) < CAST('08:15' AS TIME) THEN 'P' 
             ELSE 'L' 
        END) AS status
FROM CTE;
```

Some more points:

- Don't name aliases things like `IN` that are already key words.  That is why I gave it the name `IN_DT`.
- There is no reason to cast to a `TIME` to compare to `NULL`.
- I don't see a reason to cast to `NVARCHAR(50)` in the outer `CASE` expression.

Comment: What's the benefits of using `BETWEEN` here `BETWEEN '2019-11-03' AND '2019-11-03'`?